# Should the index.ts be resolved by TypeScript as default module file?

Tags: typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

I am trying to get work the module resolution under typescript.

If I have:

```
/modulename/index.ts
```

should it be resolved by:

```
import * as modulename from "modulename"
```

?

I can't get it work. But

```
import * as modulename from "modulename/index"
```

works well.

**Edit**

as [aluan-haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) recommended me it is neccessary to have the tsc configured properly.

This one worked for me:

```
{
   ...
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   ...
}
```

**Edit**

Please note this configuration does not work when used with VS. If it is placed in external tsconfig file the compilation works well but language service can't handle it. If its is placed in msconfig (csporj) both, compiltion and language service fails.

Only the one solution I have found to be working for 100% is to create something like:

```
src
   node_modules
      module_being_currently_developed
         submodules
```

In this case the module resolution works properly.

Comment: Is this a local module? If so I think it should be a relative path like `import * as m from "./modulename"`.

Comment: Its currently a local module, but I want to put it to npm later. so basically, i want to simulate its under node_modules folder.

Comment: Be cautious because, as noted in my answer, baseUrl is not a native NodeJS concept and so you will need something like Webpack or SystemJS to load from it. You may want to consider adding a stub package.json and using npm link if you are targeting NodeJS on the server

Comment: Yep, I need to get it work in IDE first, then I'll handle it somehow. I am targetting "amd" in the end so I'll handle it somehow. I just wanted to avoid to have that index everywhere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not a problem. RequireJS is an excellent, tried and true tool. You will find the `--paths` option to be very helpful as well with an AMD or System.register loader. GL HF!

Comment: I need to write a custom loader / module packer fro my purposes ;)

Comment: @Fis that's no small task. There are some pretty flexible loaders out there you can probably leverage. Granted it would be fun to write a loader but it's not trivial by any means so good luck to you.

Comment: Loader will be easy but I am afraid of bundler... Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends primarily on the `--moduleResolution` flag (`compilerOptions.moduleResultion` in **tsconfig.json**)

Automatic resolution of a directory to a file named `index` in that directory is a ***NodeJS convention***. This convention propagated to client-side development but it remains a convention nevertheless. It is not part of the ECMAScript module specification or the AMD specification.

When specifying `--moduleResolution node` TypeScript will follow this convention.

Additionally, when the `--module` flag (`compilerOptions.module` in **tsconfig.json**) is set to `commonjs` this convention is applied automatically even in the absence of the `--moduleResolution` flag.

Note that the setting applies to both application code and to dependencies in directories such as `node_modules`, `jspm_packages`, and `bower_components`.

While it makes the most sense for CommonJS projects, setting `--moduleResolution node` can be advantageous in other module formats as it aids in the resolution of dependencies as well as avoids certain pitfalls that come with the alternative `classic` resolution mode.

Be advised however, that loaders such as RequireJS and SystemJS will not automatically pick up this convention in your app source code so use of explicit index files in module specifiers is still recommended when importing your own app code.

In spite of the CommonJS bent of the `--moduleResolution node` settings, I still prefer and recommend even though I do not use CommonJS, Webpack, or Browserify in the browser (when I can possibly avoid them).

My loader of choice is SystemJS, and my package manager of Choice is JSPM, but I still prefer to use the node resolution scheme because it makes importing dependencies easier, thanks in part to JSPM's auto configuring of the SystemJS loader.

Now, let us move on to `--baseUrl` as it applies to your scenario.

You are attempting to import a local module as

```
import * as modulename from "modulename";
```

and have set `--module commonjs` and `--baseUrl /` in an attempt an import the local module as if it were a third party package to prepare your codebase for its splitting off into a discrete package. This, I might add, is good planning, so :+10 for that!

However, if you plan to use a CommonJS modules (something I again advise against for browser only applications), you should most definitely set your `"baseUrl"` to `"."` rather than, `"/"`. Even then, tools like the Native NodeJS require function have no support for the baseUrl concepts that originated in the browser tooling world. Webpack however, does support it.

At any rate, to load modules that are part of your own source code using a module specifier that is not a relative or absolute URL, I recommend the following regardless (be aware of loader requirements!):

1. Set `"baseURl"` to `"."`
2. Set `"moduleResolution"` to `"node"`,
3. Set `"module"` explicitly to `"commonjs"`, `"system"`, or `"amd"` (I advise against `"umd"`).
4. If not using `"commonjs"` under node, consider using `"paths"` as it allows for some very sophisticated restructuring.

Comment: I have "baseUrl": "/", "module": "commonjs", "moduleResolution": "node" and it still seems not to be working :(

Comment: "baseUrl"  should only be used together with "commonjs" in Webpack or possibly Browserify projects. Never NodeJS projects. Even then it should not be "/", but rather ".".

Comment: Is this a local module you are requiring or dependency?

Comment: Its currently a local module, but I want to put it to npm later. so basically, i want to simulate its under node_modules folder.

Comment: gotcha. let me add some info on that

Comment: it started working when I used "baseUrl": ".", I think, the "/" is resoluted as root folder. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a slash in the folder (module) name, this will treat index.ts as the folder index.

```
import * as modulename from "modulename/"
```