# Unable to export/import class from module/namespace in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm playing around with TypeScript and export/import.

I simply want to have a file-structure like in `C#`. I want to nest a helper-class whic only contains some constant string-properties. This is what the file `~/Scripts/Helper/UrlHelper.ts` looks like:

```
module Helper.UrlHelper {
    abstract class Controller {
        protected static readonly controllerName: string;
    }

    export abstract class Account extends Controller {
        static controllerName: string = "Account";

        static readonly loginGet: string = [Account.controllerName, "Login"].join("/");
        static readonly loginPost: string = [Account.controllerName, "Login"].join("/");
    }
}
```

My goal is to use the values e.g. `Helper.UrlHelper.Account.loginPost`. But I don't get the import/export to work.

My last try was to add `export * from "./Helper/UrlHelper"` and use the import `import {Account} from "../Helper/UrlHelper";`

This leads to the error:

> Module '".../Scripts/Helper/UrlHelper"' has no exported member 'Account'

I tried nearly everything from [here](http://bigfontblog.azurewebsites.net/typescript-import-and-export-organization/), but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the keyword `module`, just export the members you need to import elsewhere:

```
// Helper/UrlHelper.ts
abstract class Controller {
    protected static readonly controllerName: string;
}

export abstract class Account extends Controller {
    static controllerName: string = "Account";

    static readonly loginGet: string = [Account.controllerName, "Login"].join("/");
    static readonly loginPost: string = [Account.controllerName, "Login"].join("/");
}
```

Then, the exported member `Account` can be imported:

```
// other-directory/other-file.ts
import { Account } from "../Helper/UrlHelper"
```

The documentation on *modules* is here:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

You could also use *namespaces* but it isn't an ES6 standard. If you really want namespaces, here is the documentation:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37572180/3786294
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39827997/3786294

Comment: On top of this answer, another helpful tip is that import's also work at the folder level if you have an index file in the folder, e.g. `import { Account } from '../Helper';` If you have a file called `index.ts` in the Helper folder. In the index file, you will need to include the code `export * from './UrlHelper';`. Handy for then only needing 1 line for importing all your helpers.

Comment: @TimBJames Interesting. But is it described somewhere? Is it a robust solution that works with all protocols (AMD, CommonJS, ES6) and all bundlers/loaders?

Comment: I am not 100%, some more info is here though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028806/should-the-index-ts-be-resolved-by-typescript-as-default-module-file

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html
You're advised to not wrap classes in modules as it can become unnecessarily confusing.
A better option would be:

```
abstract class Controller { /* ... */ }
export abstract class Account extends Controller { /* ... */ }
```

This is could be placed in a `Helper` naming the file UrlHelper.ts as suggested.
Then later on when you want to import the class, you do:

```
import { Account } from "./Helper/UrlHelper";
```