# Typescript export from folder using index.ts file throws error TS2307

Tags: typescript

I have Scene.ts file, which imports files from Objects folder

```
import { Camera, Plane, Cube } from './Objects';
```

In objects folder i have 4 files:

1. Camera.ts
2. Plane.ts
3. Cube.ts
4. index.ts

All four files has similar structure

```
import SceneRenderer from './../SceneRenderer'

export default class Plane/Cube/Camera implements SceneRenderer {

    constructor(public gl:WebGLRenderingContext) {

    }

    draw() {

    }

}
```

index.ts file exports all classes from others

```
export { default as Plane } from './Plane';
export { default as Camera } from './Camera';
export { default as Cube } from './Cube';
```

In **src** folder i have file **Scene.ts** file which import all of them:

```
import { Camera, Plane, Cube } from './Objects';
```

**PROBLEM**

> src/Scene.ts:1:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './Objects'.

What is wrong?!

source code you can find [here](https://github.com/aliskhanoff/TestTask)

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44029212/729146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

index.ts should be like this

```
export * from '/Plane';
export * from '/Camera';
export * from './Cube';
```

Scene.ts should be like this

```
import { Plane, Camera, Cube} from './Objects';
```

Comment: it not works, but i solved my problem adding  "moduleResolution": "node" in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem adding "moduleResolution": "node" in tsconfig.json. Thanks everyone!